# MemSQL Column Storage InMemory

Tags: in-memory-database, singlestore

Is it possible to store columnoriented tables inmemory in Memsql? Standard is row oriented tables in memory, column oriented on disk.

Comment: Its worth noting that, as of 4.1, the last 100k rows inserted into a columnstore table (per partition) live in memory.  This allows you to do small write queries (single inserts, etc), without screwing over your segments, but I'm not sure if this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MemSQL columnstore tables are always disk-backed, however columnstore data is of course cached in memory, so if all your data happens to fit in memory you will get in-memory performance. (The disk only needs to be involved in that writes must persist to disk for durability, and after restart data must be loaded from disk before it can be read, just like for any durable in-memory store.)

In the rowstore, we use data structures and algorithms (e.g. lockfree skiplists) that take advantage of the fact that the data is in-memory to improve performance on point reads and writes, especially with high concurrency, but columnstore query execution works on fast scans over blocks of data and batch writes, which works well whether the data resides in-memory or on-disk.

Comment: alright, but there still is a difference in the storage between the two right? 
http://docs.memsql.com/2.6/concepts/columnar.html#column-oriented-versus-row-oriented-storage

My question was if there is a way to force the way row tables are stored (disk and RAM wise) to columnstore.

Comment: Yes, the storage format is certainly different. You are asking whether there's a way to store a column-oriented table in-memory only, correct? Does my answer above (that in MemSQL, column-oriented tables always reside on disk, but data is cached in memory) not answer this question? Because the storage format is so different, we don't really need to restrict column-oriented tables to in-memory size only.

Comment: yes correct. Thanks for your help i know what you mean now.